# NSMutableAttributedString fails to get custom fonts from rtf file, on iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, custom-font, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm using 3 custom fonts in my app (London,century-schoolbook,Jacob_bold). Using this code i set attributed text from file to textView.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text1 =[NSMutableAttributedString.alloc
                                       initWithFileURL:[ NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"text48" withExtension:@"rtf"]
                                       options:nil
                                       documentAttributes:nil
                                       error:nil
                                       ];
 [self.textView setAttributedText:text1];
```

and it works proper for iOS7. 2 different fonts on this page.

> СОЛОМЕНСКИЕ ЯЙЦА{
>       NSFont = " font-family: \"London\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 48.00pt";
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 1, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null),
>   BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0,
>   HeaderLevel 0"; } {
>       NSFont = " font-family: \"Century Schoolbook\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size:
>   14.00pt";
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 1, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null),
>   BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0,
>   HeaderLevel 0"; } {
>       NSFont = " font-family: \"Century Schoolbook\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size:
>   14.00pt";
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 3, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null),
>   BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0,
>   HeaderLevel 0"; } Я родился на Соломенке, улица Максима Кривоноса, и
>   стал пятым жильцом в комнате 18 квадратных метров, в нагрузку к
>   имевшимся уже там родителям, бабушке и сестре Люсе. Кроме нас, в этой
>   ничем не примечательной коммуналке жили ещё четыре семьи. Воспоминания
>   об этом важнейшем отрезке жизни ( «как вы жизню распочнёте, так она и
>   потечёт» - бабушка!), размытые и тёплые.

but for iOS 8 i get or 1 custom font for all

> СОЛОМЕНСКИЕ ЯЙЦА {
>       NSFont = " font-family: \"London\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 48.00pt";
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 1, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null),
>   BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0,
>   HeaderLevel 0"; }     Я родился на Соломенке, улица Максима Кривоноса, и
>   стал пятым жильцом в комнате 18
>
> ... 
>       Типичная яйцемодель устройства общества. Именно этими мыслями была полна моя голова, когда созерцательный процесс грубо прерывался
>   шлепком по попе от поймавшего меня взрослого.
>
> {
>       NSFont = " font-family: \"London\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 48.00pt";
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 3, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null),
>   BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0,
>   HeaderLevel 0"; }

or even nothing

> Со мной пробовали говорить. Мама била на жалость, говорила, что у
>   курочки на яичко были планы, из него мог бы вырасти цыплёнок. Папа же
>   поведал трагедию всей своей жизни, которую забыть я не смогу никогда.
>   Однажды, когда па
>
> ...
>
> {
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 3, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null),
>   BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0,
>   HeaderLevel 0"; }

stick ,can't find the way out. Only 1 is to use standart Mac fonts , they work proper for this cases.

!!! EDIT SPIKE WAY AROUND

Found the way around - as all works fine with system fonts & all is ok  with setting this custom fonts manualy using code below I've resolved my problem. Hope it was a personal bug or it will be fixed.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *res =[NSMutableAttributedString.alloc initWithFileURL:[ NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:dataObject.text withExtension:@"rtf"]
                                                                             options:nil
                                                                  documentAttributes:nil
                                                                               error:nil
                                     ];
    [res beginEditing];
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path1];
    __block BOOL found = NO;    [res enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, res.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        if (value) {
              NSLog(@"%@",[(UIFont *)value fontName]);
                       if ([[(UIFont *)value fontName] isEqualToString:@"HelveticaNeue"]) {
                UIFont *oldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"London" size:48.0];
                UIFont *newFont = oldFont;
                [res removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
                [res addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
                found = YES;
            }
            if ([[(UIFont *)value fontName] isEqualToString:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold"]) {
                UIFont *oldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturySchoolbook" size: 18.0];
                UIFont *newFont = oldFont;
                [res removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
                [res addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
                found = YES;
            }


        }
    }];
    if (!found) {
        // No font was found - do something else?
    }
    [res endEditing];
    [self.textView setAttributedText:res];
```

Comment: There's website I've bookmarked with a good checklist of common mistakes when working with custom fonts, perhaps one of the suggestions would help -> [see here](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Comment: i've already tried that ( font's are properly added and set. it works perfect for iOS 7.